# Getting the original function from a derivative

Tags: partial-derivative

i know that $f_x = 4x^3 + 4xy $ is the partial derivative of the function $ f = x^4 + 2x^2y $

But how is the original function  $ f = x^4 + 2x^2y $ found from the partial derivative ?

As in, how do i reverse the process?

Comment: By integrating $f_x$ and treating $y$ as a constant.

Answer (score 5):

**Rule:**  We see $y$ as a constant. Hence we have

$$f(x)=\int f_x dx=x^4+2x^2y+g(y)$$
where $g(y)$ is any function on $y$.